# Relacionar dois vetores/arrays de tipos diferentes e ordená-los em C++

Tags: array, c++, quicksort, busca-binária

Tenho um arquivo .txt de onde preciso coletar os dados (será colocado abaixo). A primeira coluna refere-se ao código da peça e a segunda refere-se ao nome da peça. Preciso achar uma maneira de ordenar o código com a peça para depois usar um mecanismo de busca para um cliente pesquisar a peça possuindo o código em mãos. Fiz a ordenação por Quick Sort e a busca por Busca Binária.

Estou em dúvida em como deixar o `iCodigo` junto com o `sPeca` relacionados mesmo depois da ordenação. A ideia seria criar dois vetores e tentar relacioná-los de alguma meneira.

O arquivo TXT:

```
54 ARRUELA  
93 ABRACADEIRA 
55 PINO 
49 PORCA 
60 RELE 
30 DISJUNTOR 
27 FUSIVEL 
72 MOUSE 
40 LAMPADA 
14 TECLA 
21 CAIXA 
33 TAMPA 
76 INTERRUPTOR 
26 SOQUETE  
7 BASE
63 LAMINA  
50 PLACA 
31 TUBO 
17 LATERAL 
92 VIDEO 
11 PLUG 
36 CABO 
52 SUPORTE 
83 BOTAO 
22 PARAFUSO
```

O programa:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void montVetorCodigo(int *v, int n, int x);
void montVetorPeca(string *vP, int n, string x);
void showVetorCodigo(int *v, int n);
void showVetorPeca(string *v, int n);
int buscaBinaria(int v[], int n, int x);
void quickSort(int *v, int esq, int dir);
int separar(int *v, int esq, int dir);
void trocar(int *v, int i, int j);

int main()
{
    fstream arquivo;
    string sArqNome,sLinha,sCodigo,sPeca;
    int iCodigo,iQtdLinhas=0,n;
    char cOp;

    cout << "Entre com o nome do arquivo: ";
    cin >> sArqNome;
    arquivo.open(sArqNome);
    if (arquivo.is_open()){
        while(!arquivo.eof()){  // contar as linhas para definir n
            getline(arquivo,sLinha);
            iQtdLinhas++;
        }
        n = iQtdLinhas;
        int iVetorCodigo[n];
        string sVetorPeca[n];
        int iQtdLinhas=0;
        arquivo.clear();
        arquivo.seekg(ios::beg);
        while(!arquivo.eof()){  // montagem do vetor coletando dados das colunas
            getline(arquivo,sLinha);
            sCodigo = sLinha.substr(0,2);
            sPeca = sLinha.substr(2,14);
            iCodigo = stoi(sCodigo);  // transformar string para int
            sPeca.erase(remove(sPeca.begin(), sPeca.end(), ' '), sPeca.end());  // remover espaços em branco da captura da string 'sPeca'
            cout << iCodigo << endl;
            cout << sPeca << endl;
            montVetorCodigo(iVetorCodigo,n,iCodigo);
            montVetorPeca(sVetorPeca,n,sPeca);
            iQtdLinhas++;
        }
        showVetorCodigo(iVetorCodigo,n);
        showVetorPeca(sVetorPeca,n);
        quickSort(iVetorCodigo,0,n-1);  // ordenação do vetor
        cout << endl;
        do{
            buscaBinaria(iVetorCodigo,n,iCodigo);  // mostrar a peça referente ao código digitado
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Deseja continuar a pesquisa?(Digite 's' para SIM e 'n' para NAO)-> ";
            cin >> cOp;
            cin.ignore();
            cout << endl;
        } while (cOp == 's' || cOp == 'S');
    }else{
            cout << "Arquivo nao encontrado" << endl;
    }
    arquivo.close();
    return 0;
}

void montVetorCodigo(int *v, int n, int x){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        v[i] = x;
    }
}

void montVetorPeca(string *vP, int n, string x){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vP[i] = x;
    }
}

void showVetorCodigo(int *v, int n){
    cout << "Indices:   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Elementos: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void showVetorPeca(string *vP, int n){
    cout << "Indices:   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Elementos: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << vP[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// algoritmo de busca binária
int buscaBinaria(int v[], int n, int x){
    cout << "Digite o codigo referente a peca desejada: ";
    cin >> x;
    int esq = -1, dir = n;
    while (esq < dir - 1){
        int meio = (esq + dir) / 2;
        if (v[meio] < x) esq = meio;
        else dir = meio;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "CODIGO: " << x << endl;
    cout << "PECA: " << dir << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return dir;
}

// algoritmo de ordenação quick sort
void quickSort(int *v, int esq, int dir){
    if (esq < dir){
        int j = separar(v, esq, dir);
        quickSort(v, esq, j - 1);
        quickSort(v, j + 1, dir);
    }
}

int separar(int *v, int esq, int dir){
    int iPivo = v[esq];
    int i = esq + 1;
    int j = dir;
    while (i <= j){
        if (v[i] <= iPivo)
            i++;
        else if (v[j] > iPivo)
            j--;
        else if (i <= j){
            trocar(v,i,j);
        }
    }
    trocar(v,esq,j);
    return j;
}

void trocar(int *v, int i, int j){
    int iAux;
    iAux = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = iAux;
}
```

Nessa parte em específico só consigo coletar o último código e a última peça, sendo armazenado o mesmo valor em todos os índices do array.

```
montVetorCodigo(iVetorCodigo,n,iCodigo);
montVetorPeca(sVetorPeca,n,sPeca);
```

Ficando com o resultado mostrado pela função `showVetorCodigo` e `showVetorPeca` da seguinte maneira:

```
Indices:     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
Elementos:  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22  22
Indices:     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
Elementos: PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO PARAFUSO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henrique, existem várias formas de fazer isso.

1. Manter os dados em dois vetores diferentes, mas realizar operações espelhadas.

Você vai ter um vetor de inteiros e um de string. Porém qualquer operação que você fizer em um vetor, tem que fazer no outro. Por exemplo, se durante a ordenação você fizer uma troca entre as posições `i` e `j` no vetor de inteiros, também a deve fazer no vetor de Strings. Dessa forma você garante que a relação entre código e nome da peça será coerente mesmo após qualquer operação que você fizer.

2. Manter os dados juntos num mesmo vetor.

Você pode fazer isso utilizando um vetor de `pair<int, string>`, ou de objetos da classe `Produto` com propriedades código e nome. Com isso você vai ter as duas informações sempre  juntas e pode continuar operando do jeito que você opera.

3. Utilizar um `map`.

Um map é uma estrutura de dados estruturada com chaves e valores. Você pode organizar seu map com o código como chave e o nome do produto como valor. Ele também vem com as operações de busca, inserção e modificação prontas. A busca no map tem eficiência logarítmica assim como na busca binária.

Caso não tenha ficado claro posso adicionar mais detalhes, espero ter ajudado.